# TFS 2010 : Check out file on open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I have a number of projects that include certain files that I use for creating block diagrams, etc. (*.graphml, *.doc, *.docx to be exact).  While I have setup the files to 'open with' the appropriate editor, I have to manually check them out in TFS to make them 'writeable'  It seems that there should be a way to have TFS check the files out automatically like it does for code, xml, etc.  How can I go about achieving this??

**NOTE:**
My TFS options are set to 'automatically check out' files, to no avail.

Comment: Could it make sense to store such elements within Sharepoint instead of source control? My decision bases on the following simple rule: if they are part of the build, they belong to source control - if not they 're stored in Sharepoint instead.

Comment: Well then your critical documentation is spread out all over the place.  When I am working on a project, the last thing I want to do is to go on a goose chase looking for docs.  And what about different diagrams, etc. for different versions of the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programs are required to have their own integration with TFS to be able to perform a Check-out of the files when needed. Opening Files in applications that are not "TFS Aware" requires **you** to check them out in Visual Studio or Explorer + TF Power Tools before you start wok on them. Even opening SQL files with SSMS, if they are not in a database project, requires you to perform a Check-out.

Some applications can work with TFS via [MSSCCI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx) (Misky), but these are mostly programming tools (IDE's etc) as far as I know.

This will all be fixed in TFS 2012 with the introduction of [Local Workspaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/02/version-control-model-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx).

Comment: That is a whole lot of words to say 'no, TFS / VS can't do that'

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools>Options> 
Select Source Control under options. 
Select Environment under Source Control

There is a section called 'Checked-in items' 
for the Editing dropdown select ' Check out automatically'